# How does Windows "netstat -b" determine the name of the process that owns each socket?

Tags: windows, api, sockets

I'm looking for the underlying API calls that netstat -b is using to determine the owning processes for each socket.   Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the IPHelper APIs, in this case specifically [GetExtendedTcpTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365928(v=VS.85).aspx) and [GetOwnerModuleFromTcpEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366003(v=VS.85).aspx)